# Пропадают текстуры

Tags: javascript, three.js

Всем привет,кто знает почему в некоторых файлах пропадают грани.
 К примеру и так на разных объектах[image]

а так же некоторые объекты stl имеют черный цвет или вообще не отображаються 
в блендере все корректно. Использую three.js obj(stl,mtl)loaders.

Answer (score 0):

В `three.js` предполагается, что порядок вершин в лицевых гранях должен быть против часовой стрелки. На рисунке выглядит так, будто у некоторых лицевых граней этот порядок по часовой стрелке - в этом случае считается, что грань оборотная.

Можно попробовать использовать

```
mesh.material.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
```

Чтобы не заморачиваться с изменением моделей.

Comment: да тут не в модели дело,основная часть моделей хорошо отображается, я думал дело в модели,но в блендере она хорошо отображается
вот ссылка на код https://jsfiddle.net/ukxrduko/

Comment: То, что хорошо отображается в блендере, при экспорте может, к примеру, для некоторых граней выдать больше или наоборот меньше трех вершин. Результат отображения модели с такими гранями в `Three.js`-сцене может получиться неожиданным.

Comment: так как быть то?)

Comment: Чем не устраивает вариант с двухсторонним материалом для граней? )

Comment: не меняется ничего),код смотрели?

Comment: Значит, что-то случается при экспорте таких сложных моделей.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59631/discussion-between-michael-and-prisoner849).